# Number of valid elements Matrix*Matrix transpose

Tags: calculus, matrices

I am trying to find an analytical method to find the number of valid elements in a `matrix*matrix^T` from the matrix without the need of doing the multiplication. I call valid elements all elements which multiplication is not zero. I'll give a brief example:
Say we have this matrix `A`:

```
1 2 0
4 0 0
2 3 5
```

and its transposed `T`:

```
1 4 2
2 0 3
0 0 5
```

Let's call `Zij` = Number of elements valid of row `i` of `A` when multiply by column `j` of `T`. For instance, 
`Z00 = N_valids(1*1+2*2+0*0) = 2`
`Z10 = N_valids(4*1+0*2+0*0) = 1`
Following this we'll have `Z`:

```
2 1 2
1 1 1
2 1 3
```

I would like to know if somebody knows how to find out `Z` from `A`. The diagonal elements its clear, but not the rest...

Comment: I've removed [tag:algebra] tag, since we don't use algebra tag anymore, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/3081#3081) for details. Maybe [tag:linear-algebra] would be appropriate for this question. I don't think that [tag:calculus] fits this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the matrix $A$ and create a new matrix $B$ by replacing all non-zero elements by $1$.

Example: For $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&0\\4&0&0\\2&3&5\end{pmatrix}$ you get $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&0\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

The numbers you want are precisely the entries of the matrix $BB^T$.

Example: $BB^T=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&0\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&0&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&2\\1&1&1\\2&1&3\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @ Martin: Awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

The number $Z_{i,j}$ is the number of columns for which both row $i$ and row $j$ of the matrix have a nonzero entry. So you could make a bitvector for each row indicating the nonzero positions, take bitwise-OR of those vectors two-by-two, and sum the bits of the result to give you entries $Z_{i,j}$ (which are of course symmetric, saving almost half the work).